# Making a react-native login form, looks good until user attempts to use keyboard. How keep the components from compacting on screen?

Tags: android, scrollview, react-native, textinput

Currently building a static login/info page.  The form will ask for a name, email,  phone number, gender and birthday.  I used ScrollView to wrap around both containers. The first container has 3 TextInputs and radio buttons.  The second container  has 3 Pickers for the user to enter their birthday.  Everything looks relatively fine until I attempt to enter info.  As soon as I click on the TextInputs, the onscreen keyboard compacts/distorts the rest of the components making it impossible to read what is being entered and making the rest of the page look pretty unsightly.

I think that the reason this is happening is due to the ScrollView attempting to keep all of the components on the screen.  How do I make it so that when TextInput is used, only the keyboard and that particular TextInput are visible.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  AppRegistry,
  Picker,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  Alert,
  } from 'react-native';

import RadioForm, {RadioButton, RadioButtonInput,
     RadioButtonLabel} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';


let radio_props = [
    {label: 'male', value: "male" },
    {label: 'female', value: "female" }
];
export default class SimpleComponentOne extends Component {
    constructor(radio_props){
        super(radio_props);
        this.state = {
            month: 'Month',
            day: 'day',
            year: 'year',
            gender: 'male',
            check: true
        }

    }

    onValueChangeMonth(key, value){
        this.setState({month: value})
    }

    onValueChangeDay(key, value) {
        this.setState({day: value})
    }

    onValueChangeYear(key, value) {
        this.setState({year: value})
    }
    onValueChangeGender(key, value) {
        this.setState({gender: value})
    }

    _createAlert(){
        Alert.alert("well done")
    }

    checkBoxTest(){
        //Alert.alert("this is working")
        this.setState({
            check:!this.state.check

        })
        Alert.alert("The value is now " + !this.state.check)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Text>Enter your info below</Text>

            <View style={styles.container1}
                behavior="padding"
                >
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Please enter your name"
                    style={styles.name}        
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Please enter your phone number"
                    style={styles.phoneNumber}
                />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Please enter your email"
                    style={styles.email}
                />
                <View style={styles.gender}>
                    <Text style={styles.genderText}>Please choose gender
                    </Text>
                    <RadioForm
                        style={styles.genderSelect}
                        radio_props={radio_props}
                        initial={-1}
                        // formHorizontal={true}
                        onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
                        buttonSize={5}
                        buttonColor='black'
                        buttonColorLabel='black'
                        labelColor='black'
                        // labelHorizontal={false}
                        labelStyle={{fontSize:12}}
                    >

                    </RadioForm>
                </View>
            </View>

            <Text>Please enter your birthday

                </Text> 

            <View style={styles.container2}>

                <View style={styles.month}>
                    <Text>Month: </Text>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.month}
                        onValueChange={this.onValueChangeMonth.bind(this,'month')}
                        prompt="Pick your month"
                        mode="dropdown"
                    >
                        <item label="January" value="January"/>
                        <item label="Febuary" value="Febuary"/>
                        <item label="March" value="March"/>
                        <item label="April" value="April"/>
                        <item label="May" value="May"/>
                        <item label="June" value="June"/>
                        <item label="July" value="July"/>
                        <item label="August" value="August"/>
                        <item label="September" value="September"/>
                        <item label="October" value="October"/>
                        <item label="November" value="November"/>
                        <item label="December" value="December"/>
                    </Picker>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.day}>
                    <Text>Day: </Text>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.day}
                        onValueChange={this.onValueChangeDay.bind(this, 'day')}
                        prompt="Pick the day"
                        mode='dropdown'
                    >
                        <item label="1" value="1"/>
                        <item label="2" value="2"/>
                        <item label="3" value="3"/>
                        <item label="4" value="4"/>
                        <item label="5" value="5"/>
                        <item label="6" value="6"/>
                        <item label="7" value="7"/>
                        <item label="8" value="8"/>
                        <item label="9" value="9"/>
                        <item label="10" value="10"/>
                        <item label="11" value="11"/>
                        <item label="12" value="12"/>
                        <item label="13" value="13"/>
                        <item label="14" value="14"/>
                        <item label="15" value="15"/>
                        <item label="16" value="16"/>
                        <item label="17" value="17"/>
                        <item label="18" value="18"/>
                        <item label="19" value="19"/>
                        <item label="20" value="20"/>
                        <item label="21" value="21"/>
                    </Picker>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.year}>
                    <Text>Year:</Text>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.year}
                        onValueChange={this.onValueChangeYear.bind(this, 'year')}
                        mode='dropdown'
                        prompt='Please pick the year you were born'
                    >   
                        <item label="2000" value="2000"/>
                        <item label="1999" value="1999"/>
                        <item label="1998" value="1998"/>
                        <item label="1997" value="1997"/>
                        <item label="1996" value="1996"/>
                        <item label="1995" value="1995"/>
                        <item label="1994" value="1994"/>
                    </Picker>

                </View>

            </View>
            <Button
                    title="Press to submit"
                    color="#841584"
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={this._createAlert}
                >

                </Button> 
        </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer:{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        // backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    },
    container1: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        // backgroundColor: 'green'
        paddingBottom: 20, 

    },
    container2:{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        // backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
        width: 100+'%',

        justifyContent: 'flex-end',

    },

    email: {
        width: 100+"%",
        flex: 1,
        // backgroundColor: 'yellow'

    },
    name: {
       width: 100+'%',
        // backgroundColor: 'red',
        flex:1, 

    },
    gender:{
        flex:1,
        // backgroundColor: 'blue',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: 100+'%',
        paddingBottom:10

    },
    genderText:{
        paddingBottom: 5,
        paddingTop: 10,
    },
    genderSelect:{
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        width: 100+"%",
        // backgroundColor:'purple'
    },
    month:{
        flex: 1
    },
    day: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    year: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    button:{
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom:10,

    },

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll either need to use a combination of `onLayout` to get the coordinates of your `TextInput` and then use `onFocus` to fire `scrollTo()` (pass those coordinates) on your `ScrollView`...

or use a library like this one: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: Thank you for responding. Sorry about the delayed response.  I took a small break.